# Pivot in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, rank

i have an oracle table names as occupations as:

```
NAME      OCCUPATION    
Ashley    Professor  
Samantha  Actor  
Julia     Doctor  
Britney   Professor  
Maria     Professor  
Meera     Professor  
Priya     Doctor  
Priyanka  Professor  
Jennifer  Actor  
Ketty     Actor  
Belvet    Professor  
Naomi     Professor  
Jane      Singer    
Jenny     Singer  
Kristeen  Singer  
Christeen Singer  
Eve       Actor
```

I'd like to turn my keys into columns using plain SQL (not PL/SQL) so that the resulting table would look something like this:

```
DOCTOR  PROFESSOR   SINGER      ACTOR    
Julia   Ashley      Christeen   Eve    
Priya   Belvet      Jane        Jennifer    
Null    Britney     Jenny       Ketty                 
Null    Maria       Kristeen    Samantha     
Null    Meera       Null        Null             
Null    Naomi       Null        Null   
Null    Priyanka    Null        Null
```

I am using following query for this:

```
select * from
(select name,occupation,RANK() over (partition by occupation order by name) as rank from occupations)
pivot (
max(name) 
for occupation in ('Doctor', 'Professor', 'Singer', 'Actor')
);
```

But this query is giving error as sql commond not properly ended.

Comment: you did not post the error

Comment: If you want us to help you need to post the error message. Don't expect us to guess.

Comment: sql commond not properly ended. this was the error dude

Comment: It's not clear from your data how you relate the records together - e.g. why is the doctor "Julia" associated with the professor "Ashley", singer "Christeen", and actor "Eve"? There's something missing in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

your query according to your requirement is not matching:

**please note**: since in relational database, for each row, columns should have relationship on each other , but according to your requirement col1 and col2 is not having any relation, so we can do something like below
Please check this.

```
select     min (case upper(OCCUPATION) when 'DOCTOR' then name end)   as DOCTOR
           ,min (case upper(OCCUPATION) when 'PROFESSOR' then name end)   as PROFESSOR
           ,min (case upper(OCCUPATION) when 'SINGER' then name end)   as SINGER
           ,min (case upper(OCCUPATION) when 'ACTOR' then name end)   as ACTOR

from       (select    name,OCCUPATION   
                       ,row_number () over (  partition by    name,OCCUPATION order by  OCCUPATION ) as rn

            from        test where upper(OCCUPATION) IN ('DOCTOR','PROFESSOR','SINGER','ACTOR')
            )

group by     name,OCCUPATION 
order by     1,2,3,4 ;
```

OUTPUT

```
DOCTOR  PROFESSOR   SINGER  ACTOR
Julia           
Priya           
       Ashley       
       Belvet       
       Britney      
       Maria        
       Meera        
       Naomi        
       Priyanka     
                 Christeen  
                 Jane   
                 Jenny  
                 Kristeen   
                               Eve
                               Jennifer
                               Ketty
                               Samantha
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you are looking for.  Next time a create table and insert statements as a starting point to work from would be appreciated.

```
create table t (
       name       varchar2(100),
       occupation varchar2(100)
);

insert into t values ('Ashley'    ,'Professor');
insert into t values ('Samantha'  ,'Actor');  
insert into t values ('Julia'     ,'Doctor');  
insert into t values ('Britney'   ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Maria'     ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Meera'     ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Priya'     ,'Doctor');  
insert into t values ('Priyanka'  ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Jennifer'  ,'Actor');  
insert into t values ('Ketty'     ,'Actor');  
insert into t values ('Belvet'    ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Naomi'     ,'Professor');  
insert into t values ('Jane'      ,'Singer');    
insert into t values ('Jenny'     ,'Singer');  
insert into t values ('Kristeen'  ,'Singer');  
insert into t values ('Christeen' ,'Singer');  
insert into t values ('Eve'       ,'Actor');

WITH doctor AS
 (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,
         NAME
    FROM t
   WHERE occupation = 'Doctor'),
professor AS
 (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,
         NAME
    FROM t
   WHERE occupation = 'Professor'),
singer AS
 (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,
         NAME
    FROM t
   WHERE occupation = 'Singer'),
actor AS
 (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY NAME) AS rn,
         NAME
    FROM t
   WHERE occupation = 'Actor')
SELECT d.name AS doctor,
       p.name AS professor,
       s.name AS singer,
       a.name AS actor
  FROM (SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
          FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX(ct)
                               FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ct
                                       FROM t
                                      GROUP BY occupation))) x
  LEFT JOIN doctor d
    ON d.rn = x.lvl
  LEFT JOIN professor p
    ON p.rn = x.lvl
  LEFT JOIN singer s
    ON s.rn = x.lvl
  LEFT JOIN actor a
    ON a.rn = x.lvl;
```

[image: Results]